# How to operate on parameters of python itertools.product

Tags: python

```
Itertools.product(*args, **kargs)
```

I see that product can receive many paramters. like

```
a = [1,2]
b = [3,4]
and I can itertools.product(a,b,a,b,a,b....)
```

What I want to do is to collect all parameters in one structure.
Because I may not know how many sets I have to calculate the product.

But

```
itertools.product([a,b,a,b])
```

don't work.

So, how should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just unpack the list using `itertools.product(*[a, b, a, b])`.

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2]

In [2]: b = [3, 4]

In [3]: from itertools import product

In [4]: list(product(a, b, a, b))
Out[4]: 
[(1, 3, 1, 3),
 (1, 3, 1, 4),
 (1, 3, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 2, 4),
 ...]

In [5]: test_list = [a, b, a, b]

In [6]: list(product(*test_list))
Out[6]: 
[(1, 3, 1, 3),
 (1, 3, 1, 4),
 (1, 3, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 2, 4),
 ...]
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)